# Python Clearing A List For Use in Tkinter Widget

Tags: python, mysql, list, tkinter

this function selects data from a MySQL table and returns it as a List. This List is then used to define a tkinter OptionMenu. The problem is that when I call this function multiple times, the list of options in the tkinter widget doubles.

```
def CreateSingleScoutAttendanceReportRaiseFrame():
    ScoutList=[]
    mycursor.execute("SELECT firstname,secondname FROM scoutinfo")
    myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresults)
    for i in myresults:
        Temp=[i[0]]+[i[1]]
        print(Temp)
        ScoutList.append(Temp)
        
    AttendanceScoutOptionMenuLabel = tk.Label(CreateSingleAttendanceReportFrame,text="Choose A Scout: ",font=LargeTextFont,bg="white")
    AttendanceScoutOptionMenuLabel.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

As you don't have access to my database, I can show you photos.

[image: First Call]
[image: Second Call]

From my understanding, I clear the list each time the function is run with the line `ScoutList=[]` as it should clear the list.
I have tried `ScoutList.clear()` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_= CreateSingleAttendanceReportFrame()

AttendanceScoutOptionMenuLabel = tk.Label(list_,text="Choose A Scout: ",font=LargeTextFont,bg="white")
```

Pretty sure that should work. You were nesting the function inside another function, and when you returned the list to it it made the list a global variable. You don't have any arguments in `CreateSingleAttendanceReportFrame` so when you say the list is empty inside that function all it does is tell your computer that you have an empty list inside that function, not that THE list is supposed to be empty.